# Proof related to combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

Show that, in a class of $15$ students, if the total of the marks in a subject is $600$, then, there is a group of $3$ students, the total of whose marks, is at least $120$.

I have only done questions related to finding the number of combinations and permutations but none related to such proofs. Any help would be much appreciated about how to start.

Comment: I think you should consider this from a probability view: what is the average score?

Comment: so if the average score becomes 40, I cant just write that three students make up a score of 120, can I?

Comment: Let $x_i$ denote the mark of student $i$ ($1 \leq i \leq 15 $) and suppose by way of contradiction that $x_i + x_j + x_k < 120$ for all pairwise distinct $i$, $j$ and $k$. What can you say about $\sum_{i = 1}^{15} x_i$?

Comment: Hint:  how many groups of three are there?  Assuming the total score of each is $≤119$ what is the most the total sum of scores of all the groups can be?  What is the total sum of scores of all the groups?

Comment: all right I think i get it now.

Answer (score 1):

If ALL the subgroups of three had less than $120$, then the total score would be less than $120\times 5 =600$ which is impossible, thus at least one subgroup of three had $120$ or more

Hope this helps